# Can we update html data of CLOB column by using SQL update?

Tags: html, sql, oracle

i have html code which i need to update in one clob column , how can i convert it in sql update string?
My second question is that how to insert ® and &  which exist in this html code.

```
<html>
<head>
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
      <div align="center" style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            <b> card<sup><font size='3'>&reg;</font></sup>  Card  Notification</b>
            <br />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            The online statement for your  card provided by {company name} and issued by Com is now available. Select the Account Maint. &amp; Statement tab to view your statement.
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            Equal Opportunity Lender.
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            This Card is issued  International Incorporated.
        </p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `quotation`. If you use `sqlplus`

```
set define off
update my table 
set my_clob_column = q'[ <html>
<head>
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
     <div>
      <div align="center" style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            <b> card<sup><font size='3'>&reg;</font></sup>  Card  Notification</b>
            <br />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <p style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            The online statement for your  card provided by {company name} and issued by Com is now available. Select the Account Maint. &amp; Statement tab to view your statement.
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            Equal Opportunity Lender.
        </p>
        <p style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
            This Card is issued  International Incorporated.
        </p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>  ]' 
where ...........
```

Comment: yeah this is the way to get the solution, just one thing need to ask that how to handle &amp; &reg; .Your solution is working but only need to insert &amp; &reg;, that is there in html code..do you know that?

Comment: if you use `sqlplus`, then use `set define off`. I updated the post

Comment: i am saving the html script in clob column and using toad for that.

Comment: @vim then this is a Toad question. It must have a way to disable substitution variables or to use a different character. Top hit: https://support.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/11560/no-prompt-for-substitution-variable-how-do-you-enable-disable-prompt-for-variable-substitution

Comment: @vim, you can use Toad the same, but run it as script ( F5 )

Comment: i just unchecked check box under “Substitution Variable Prompting” section, its working now :) thanks

Comment: @vim, you are very welcome. glad that it helped.